# why are methods implemented outside an external module still accessible to the module

Tags: c++, c, api, dynamic-loading

Having ./library.so (`rary.cpp`) and ./main (`main.cpp`) executable, both sharing the same `api.h`.

The only method (`void method (void)`) has only its signature in `api.h`, the actual implementation is in `main.cpp`.

At compile time `rary.cpp` doesn't include the actual definition of the method: `main.cpp` is never mentioned when making the `library.so` file. Still if I access the shared file via `dlopen` and `dlsym`, any calls from within `library.so` to the method do actually refer to the method which was only implemented in the main program.

I didn't expect this to happen, as far as I am aware `library.so` was never present in the implementation of the method, so the compiler (I think) should complain that a not-implemented method is being called.

So my questions are:

1. Is this normal? are methods implemented in the main binary supposed to be accessed directly from dynamically loaded modules just by their name? (I thought that there is no guarantee of how symbols can be actually called in a binary after compiling)
2. Is there a way to prevent this? Say that I am providing an API for someone to write a plugin for my program, this way they could guess the names of the methods in the main binary and do some... hack?
3. Can I expect this behavior to be consistent between compilers and operating systems?
4. Should I or is it a good practice to rely on this behavior?

---

## Source codes

### main.cpp

```
#include "api.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void method (void)
{
    cout << "method happened" << endl;
}

void method (int num)
{
    cout << "method happened with num " << num << endl;
}

int main (void)
{
    cout << "started main" << endl;

    typedef void(* initfunc)();

    void * handle = dlopen("./library.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    initfunc func = reinterpret_cast<initfunc> (dlsym(handle, "init"));

    func();

    return 0;
}
```

### rary.cpp

```
#include "api.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

extern "C" void init (void)
{
    method();
    method(69);
    cout << "library ran" << endl;
}
```

### api.h

```
void method (void);
void method (int);
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
project(apitest CXX)

add_executable(apitest "main.cpp")
add_library(rary MODULE "rary.cpp")
target_link_libraries(apitest dl)
```

### Compiling

```
cmake .
make
```

### Result

```
$ ./apitest
started core
method happened
method happened with num 69
library ran
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > *Q1. Is this normal? are methods implemented in the main binary supposed to be accessed directly from
> >     dynamically loaded modules just by their name? (I thought that there is no guarantee of how
> >     symbols can be actually called in a binary after compiling)*

Yes. By default, symbols are visible externally, except when specifically marked otherwise (with GCC at least).

> > *Q2. Is there a way to prevent this? Say that I am providing an API for someone to write a plugin for my
> >     program, this way they could guess the names of the methods in the main binary and do some... hack?*

Yes, you can prevent this by compiling the program with the option `-fvisibility=hidden`. I modified your example by adding this to the CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fvisibility=hidden")
```

I changed the definition of the init function so that it is marked visible, like so:

```
extern "C" __attribute__ ((visibility ("default"))) void init (void)
```

I also modified your main.cpp to check for errors from dlsym (as your original version did not):

```
initfunc func = reinterpret_cast<initfunc> (dlsym(handle, "init"));

if (func == NULL) {
    cout << dlerror() << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

After doing this, your program outputs the following:

```
$ ./apitest 
started main
./apitest: symbol lookup error: ./library.so: undefined symbol: _Z6methodv
```

As the init function is marked visible, so it can be called from the main function. But the `method` function is not, so you get an undefined symbol error.

> > *Q3. Can I expect this behaviour to be consistent between compilers and operating systems?*

No. It seems that on Windows the behaviour is more or less reversed - by default symbols are not exported unless explicitly marked.

> > *Q4. Should I or is it a good practice to rely on this behaviour?*

Best practice when making libraries is only to export symbols that form the libraries public API. This has a number of benefits:

- Linking time will be shorted
- Less chance of symbols clashing
- Better compiler optimization

The [GCC Wiki Visibility Page](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) (where I found most of the info for this answer) contains a lot of information about this, including best practice tips.

Answer (score 1):

it is normal for shared library in Linux.

shared libraries are not like windows dlls. in this subject it is more similar to static library.

When you compile the lib, it missing the `method`. if your main won't supply it, it just won't be able to load the library and `dlopen` will be failed and you should use `dlerror` to check why.

you can try it:

```
handle = dlopen("./library.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if (!handle) {
    cerr<< dlerror()<<endl;
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: I know nothing about Windows DLLs though, never developed there.

Comment: @Alec windows DLLs are fully linked, so you can't leave unresolved symbols.

Comment: The thing that worries me is that I am calling unlinked method which was defined with C++ linkage, and overloaded.